# handling exceptions from python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

My function is executed with threads:

```
def getdata(self, page, ...):
    tries = 10
    for n in range(tries):
        try:
            ...
            datarALL = []
            url = 'http://website/...'.format(...)
            responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False)
            responsedata.raise_for_status()
            if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
                ...
                    if ...
                        break   
        except (ChunkedEncodingError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as e:
            print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0]))
            if n == tries - 1:
                print ("page {0} could not be imported. Max retried reached.".format(page))
                os._exit(1)  #One thread max retried - close all threads and 
    return datarALL
```

as follows:

```
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_workers) as executor:
        futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata, page,...)) for page in pages]
        for data in as_completed(futh):
            datarALL.extend(data.result())
    print ("Finished generateing data.")
    return datarALL
```

Sometimes I get unexpected exceptions like: `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` which shuts down my program. I want to change my code so that no matter which exception happens the thread will allways retry untill the `if n == tries - 1:` is met. I don't want my thread to shut down due to random exception.

I read the [request exceptions info page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/) but I don't see how I can catch all the exceptions without manually listing all of them. Is there a generic way to do this?

Basicly I want something like:

```
        except (ALL EXCEPTIONS from Requests) as e:
            print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0]))
            if n == tries - 1:
                print ("page {0} could not be imported. Max retried reached.".format(page))
                os._exit(1)  #One thread max retried - close all threads and 
    return datarALL
```

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**
using

```
    except Exception as e:
        print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0]))
        if n == tries - 1:
            print ("page {0} could not be imported. Max retried reached.".format(page))
            os._exit(1)  #One thread max retried - close all threads and 
return datarALL
```

Does not catch. it gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 331, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 640, in read_chunked
    chunk = self._handle_chunk(amt)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 595, in _handle_chunk
    returned_chunk = self._fp._safe_read(self.chunk_left)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 607, in _safe_read
    chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

The loop does not retry. The run is terminated...

**EDIT2:**

```
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0]))
        if n == tries - 1:
            print ("page {0} could not be imported. Max retried reached.".format(page))
            os._exit(1)  #One thread max retried - close all threads and 
return datarALL
```

Also does not catch the `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` listed above.

Comment: `except ConnectionResetError: .....`?

Comment: @BlackThunder I want to catch all exceptions not only ConnectionError

Comment: use `except Exception:` ?

Comment: This might help you http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/

Comment: @BlackThunder This link posted in my question.. note what I wrote about it

Comment: Try: `except Exception as err: print(err)`

Comment: @BlackThunder I did that.. it did not catch the 
 ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Comment: @BlackThunder check my edit

Comment: @RoopakANelliat check my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catching all exceptions is usually considered a bad practice since it could hide some problems.

That said, Python exception benefit from inheritance and catching a base exception will catch every exception inherited from this base exception.

See [the Python standard exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionResetError) for detail.

You can see that the root exception is `BaseException`, but this one should never be catched since it will catch `Ctrl+C` interruptions and generator exits.
If you want to catch every exceptions types, you could catch `Exception`.

You could also want to catch only exception from `requests`. In that case, according to [the doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/), it can be done by catching the base exception of the `requests` module: `RequestException`

---

If you want to catch both `requests` exceptions and `ConnectionResetError` (which is a Python standard exception), you have to specify both in your `except` clause:

```
except (requests.exceptions.RequestException,
        ConnectionResetError) as err:
    # some code
```

Or if you want to be less specific and catch all possible connection errors you can use `ConnectionError` instead of `ConnectionResetError`. (see the [exceptions hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionResetError))

Finally, you may want to react differently to each exception type. In this case, you can do this:

```
try:
    # something
except ConnectionError as err:
    # manage connection errors
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    # manage requests errors
```

Comment: To make things clear I want to catch all exceptions that request package can generate. Since I don't care what is the cause I want to simply retry. Only if after 10 times there are still exceptions then I want to raise them and stop the code.

Comment: @Programmer120 Then simply catch RequestException as stated in the last paragraph

Comment: I did:  `except RequestException as e:`   it gives: `NameError: name 'RequestException' is not defined`  changed it to  except `requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:`
 and now it still doesn't catch the `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

Comment: Why ConnectionError  is not handled inside the request package?

Answer (score -3):

check your `settings.py` - whether channels added in installed app.